# Is magnetometer an IMU sensor?

Tags: accelerometer, magnetometer, gyroscope

I am just learning about orientation, hence I got confused with definition of the following:

- Inertial measurement unit (IMU).
- Magnetic and inertial measurement unit (MIMU).
- Attitude and Heading Reference System (AHRS).
- Magnetic, angular rate and gravity (MARG)

Here some example definitions/statements from several papers I am reading. From [Madgwick et al.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5975346):

> An IMU (Inertial Measurement Unit) consists of gyroscopes and
> accelerometers enabling the tracking of rotational and translational
> movements... MARG systems, also known as AHRS...

From [Ludwig et al.](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/conference-proceedings-of-spie/10598/105982L/Comparison-of-attitude-and-heading-reference-systems-using-foot-mounted/10.1117/12.2296568.short):

> A magnetic and inertial measurement unit (MIMU) consists of a 3-axis
> MEMS gyroscope, accelerometer and magnetometer.

From [Won et al.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4689397):

> An IMU consists of three accelerometers and three gyroscopes (gyros)
> that measure three linear acceleration components and three angular
> velocity components of the body frame.

From the [Python AHRS library](https://ahrs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters/madgwick.html):

> So, the estimation of the orientation using inertial sensors only
> (gyroscopes and accelerometers) becomes:

From [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_measurement_unit)

> An inertial measurement unit works by detecting linear acceleration
> using one or more accelerometers and rotational rate using one or more
> gyroscopes. Some also include a magnetometer which is commonly used
> as a heading reference. Typical configurations contain one
> accelerometer, gyro, and magnetometer per axis for each of the three
> principal axes: pitch, roll and yaw.

Are AHRS and MARG same? Do we consider magnetometer as IMU?

Comment: A magnetometer doesn't measure inertia hence it is what it basically is... a magnetometer. However if you take the signals it produces and calculate inertia then, the overall "black box" can be regarded as whatever you want to call it.

Comment: No. Magnetometer is not an IMU. Neither are gyroscopes and accelerometers. From Wikipedia: *"An inertial measurement unit (IMU) is an electronic device that measures and reports a body's specific force, angular rate, and sometimes the orientation of the body, using a combination of accelerometers, gyroscopes, and sometimes magnetometers."*, so neither of these alone is capable of reporting all the data IMU is reporting.